# SSL error with PHP curl

Tags: php, api, ssl, curl

Hello fellow programmers,

I'm making an API with a https connection. I want to secure the API call with a certificate check. Now i've downloaded the cacert.pem from curl and placed this in my folder, but it doesn't work and gives me this error:

```
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Well i'm really sure that the cacert.pem file is located correctly but for you guys some code that i've been writing to get it working:

```
 $ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST      ,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->api_key . ":" . $this->api_secret);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cacert.pem");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    ,$post_vars);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,0);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept: application/json'));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

I hope you some of you guys have an answer for my question because I really don't know much about SSL connections.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you download the cacert.pem from?

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/ has a bundle. The absolute path: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Comment: This should work; are you sure the file is readable?

Comment: Yes.. I've changed it to 777 to make sure it is readable, but I get the same error again :(

Comment: Yes. I can get the info with the file_get_contents() function. This is really weird!

Comment: Then the problem is likely to be on the server you're trying to access. Is it your own server?

Comment: Yes it is. It's from server to server connection if that's an important thing to know!

Comment: I think you will find your solution from this link: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having made sure that your certificate bundle is readable by the script you're running, the next step is to investigate the server itself.

If this is your own server, it's likely that you forgot to install the intermediate certificates, i.e. the ones in between the issued certificate and one of the certificate authorities that comes with the bundle.

If you're working with a self-signed certificate, your `cacert.pem` should contain the public certificate of the server you're connecting to; this can be generated from the private certificate, outlined [here](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html), referred to as the `.crt` file.

Comment: I'm at Step 6 from the tutorial. But i cant find the Virtual hosts file? Do you know where this is located at default?

Comment: @PaulOostenrijk It's the file that has all the `<VirtualHost>` blocks, assuming Apache.

Comment: I'm gonna check for the virtualhost file at my hosting company. I cannot find it now.. You will get an update!

Comment: I have fixed it with the virtual host. But i added my intermediate and self signed certificate to cacert. Then it worked. But is it safe?

Comment: @PaulOostenrijk The intermediate cert should be added *on your server* to form a certificate chain :)