# cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate XAMPP Wordpress

Tags: curl, xampp, localhost

I am using Orchid Store theme to set up my wordpress site. When I try to import themes demo content in localhost, I am getting "cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" error.

I tried every solution I have found:

1. I  downloaded `cacert.pem` from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
2. I updated the correct `php.ini` file by adding `curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"`
3. I then added `openssl.cafile="C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"` to `php.ini`
4. I also switched from `\` to `/`
5. I also removed the quotes `(openssl.cafile=C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem)`

After every change, I restarted the server. But, still I am getting the same error.

What else can I do? Can you please help me with it.

-Thanks

Windows 10, XAMPP, PHP 7.2.8, localhost:8080

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL error with PHP curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947064/ssl-error-with-php-curl)

Comment: enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE and post the verbose log: ```$stderrh=tmpfile();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$stderrh));
curl_exec($ch);
/* https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268 */
rewind($stderrh); 
$stderr=stream_get_contents($stderrh);
fclose($stderrh);
echo $stderr;
```

Comment: @hanshenrik I am just using an free theme and trying to import the demo data. Where should I paste this above code?